# Are there any numeral systems that start with 1x prefix?

Tags: number-systems

I know that it is customary to prefix hexadecimal numbers with `0x`. I came across this number `1X000008` and was wondering if it is hexadecimal or is it another numeral system?

Are there any numeral systems that start with `1x` prefix?

Comment: Where did you come across this? I have never seen 1X used as a prefix in a numerical notation.

Comment: the `0x` prefix is a computer science notation rather than a mathematical one, so you would probably have better luck on stack exchange. In any case, I suspect this is a typo, not a different notation.